# WebRTC Connectivity Issue

Tags: javascript, webrtc

lately I have been experimenting with WebRTC. I was trying to really wrap my head around it, while at the same time see if I could test it.

So I wrote a test that checks for two things

1. Is the connection consistent?
2. Will the number of peers slow down the connection, and if so what is the threshold before it becomes noticeable?

What I have noticed in my test, is that (1) was not true. What I found was that this tests results averages to about 10 to 20 passes out of a 100?

What I ask is for someone to take a look and let me know if I wrote my test wrong, or perhaps identify another reason for the failure.

Please note that I ran this only on Chrome 62, and the ice-server list is taken from https://github.com/DamonOehlman/freeice.

So below is a test that I wrote:

```
const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true});
const iceServers = [{
    urls: [
        "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun.ekiga.net",
        "stun:stun.ideasip.com",
        "stun:stun.rixtelecom.se",
        "stun:stun.schlund.de",
        "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478",
        "stun:stun.voiparound.com",
        "stun:stun.voipbuster.com",
        "stun:stun.voipstunt.com",
        "stun:stun.voxgratia.org"
    ]
}]

async function initExample(){
    try{
        // Init Local Connections
        var localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers});
        var remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers});

        // Create Data Channels
        var remoteDataChannel;// this is added later
        var localDataChannel = localConnection.createDataChannel('DataChannel');

        // Configure Stream
        var remoteStream;// this is added later
        localConnection.addStream(localStream)

        // Catch DataChannel when it is sent from local to remote
        remoteConnection.ondatachannel = dataChannelEvent => {
            remoteDataChannel = dataChannelEvent.channel
        }

        // Catch MediaStream when it is sent from local to remote
        remoteConnection.onaddstream = mediaStreamEvent => {
            remoteStream = mediaStreamEvent.stream;
        }

        // Create Offer
        var offer = await localConnection.createOffer();
        await localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        await remoteConnection.setRemoteDescription(localConnection.localDescription);

        // Create Answer
        var answer = await remoteConnection.createAnswer();
        await remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
        await localConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteConnection.localDescription);

        // Return Results
        return {
            localConnection, remoteConnection,
            localDataChannel, localStream,
            get remoteDataChannel(){
                return remoteDataChannel
            },
            get remoteStream(){
                return remoteStream;
            },
        }
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e)
    }
}

async function test(N=100){
    const stats = {pass:0, fail: 0, N};
    const results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        console.log({...stats, i})
        let conn = await initExample();
        if(conn.remoteDataChannel){
            stats.pass++;
        }else{
            stats.fail++;
        }
        results.push(conn);
    }
    return results;
}

var r = await test();
```

Comment: You only are checking if remoteDataChannel is properly created. Also you are not streaming, so you do not really know if the stream is available....Anyway, if you would like to check, instead of use `await`, you can check the error to improve your experiencie. Finally I would create a virtual machine to check properly the connection between peers using separate browsers.

Comment: I see, the issue in my test is that the datachannel seems not to be trasmitted sometimes to the other peer. I first noticed it when I had a similar setup between two broswers. So I wrote this test to try and simulate it. I want to point out that even when I remove the try catch. There are still no errors reported. So its like the peers are on standby

Comment: In your test, once it is open, I do not see any sent message in the data channel. Am I correct? Even that. You do not know if there is an error in your connection configuration and you do not interchange any ice-candidate...

Comment: Yes, but that was because when I do attempt to send a message when the other peer has not yet recieved the datachannel, it throws an error

Comment: Yes, because the connection is not open since the ice candidate phase was passed. I recommend this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling) from MDN

Comment: @JTejedor I think I understand the problem now. In my code I pass the iceservers through the constructor. But what this article suggested was for peers to exchange the current iceserver that they are using. This could be the source of my issues. I will experiement with this a bit and report back on this (may be helpful for others who read this)

Comment: @JTejedor thanks for your help, I posted below a test where my issue is fixed plus the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

So after @JTejedor comments and suggestion, I realized that my connection test was setup incorrectly. For anyone who is having this issue, please note, you need make sure that the peers are sending their registered ice-candidates to one another.

In my offline version this is done as follows:

```
// Map Ice Candidate
remoteConnection.onicecandidate = evt => {
    if(evt.candidate) {
        localConnection.addIceCandidate(evt.candidate)
    }
}
localConnection.onicecandidate = evt => {
    if(evt.candidate) {
        remoteConnection.addIceCandidate(evt.candidate)
    }
}
```

If you have this working with sockets (or some other server-side solution), make sure to send these over the socket to other peer.

Here is the working test (which always passes):

```
// Ice Servers
const iceServers = [{
    urls: [
        "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun.ekiga.net",
        "stun:stun.ideasip.com",
        "stun:stun.rixtelecom.se",
        "stun:stun.schlund.de",
        "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478",
        "stun:stun.voiparound.com",
        "stun:stun.voipbuster.com",
        "stun:stun.voipstunt.com",
        "stun:stun.voxgratia.org"
    ]
}]

// Run the test once
async function initExample(){
    // Init Local Connections
    var localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers});
    var remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers});//this is really "remote" its simulated

    // Map Ice Candidate
    remoteConnection.onicecandidate = evt => {
        if(evt.candidate) {
            localConnection.addIceCandidate(evt.candidate)
        }
    }
    localConnection.onicecandidate = evt => {
        if(evt.candidate) {
            remoteConnection.addIceCandidate(evt.candidate)
        }
    }

    // Create Data Channels
    var remoteDataChannel;// this is added later
    var localDataChannel = localConnection.createDataChannel('DataChannel');

    // Tie end of promise to getting the datachannel
    return new Promise( async res => {
        // Catch DataChannel when it is sent from local to remote
        remoteConnection.ondatachannel = dataChannelEvent => {
            console.log('GOT CHANNEL', dataChannelEvent)
            remoteDataChannel = dataChannelEvent.channel
            res(remoteDataChannel);
        }

        // Create Offer
        var offer = await localConnection.createOffer();
        await localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        await remoteConnection.setRemoteDescription(localConnection.localDescription);

        // Create Answer
        var answer = await remoteConnection.createAnswer();
        await remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
        await localConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteConnection.localDescription);

    })
}

// A Promisified Timeout
const promisedTimeout = (timeout = 10000) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let wait = window.setTimeout(() => {
    window.clearTimeout(wait);
    resolve(false);
  }, timeout)
})

// Run the test N times
async function test(N=100){
    // Init variables
    const stats = {pass:0, fail: 0, N};
    const results = [];

    // Loop
    for (var i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
        // log
        console.log({...stats, i});

        // This will each example against a timeout, 
        // if the timeout finishes first, then this test will be marked as fail
        let pass = await Promise.race([
            initExample(),
            promisedTimeout()
        ]);
        if(pass) {
            stats.pass ++;
        }else{
            stats.fail ++;
        }
        results.push(pass);
    }
    return {results,stats};
}

// Run the test
test()
```